# why this command using pipe doesn't work?

Tags: command-line, bash

Why does `find . | cat` works (printing all the files names) but `find . | file -i` doesn't work for showing all files mime type?

shouldn't it work since there is an output from `find .` and an input from `file -i`?

*(Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm a beginner using bash and I couldn't find another question that could explain this to me)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a pipe, the command on the right-hand side reads the data on its stdin channel. The `file` command requires the files to be command line arguments, not data on stdin.

This is exactly what the `xargs` command is for: read from stdin, and provide the data as command line arguments:

```
find . | xargs file -i
```

*Or*, use the `-f` option for `file`:

```
find . | file -i -f -
```

Read the man pages for more details.